# How do I say in German "It doesn't matter"?

Tags: word-choice

How do I say in German

> It doesn't matter how precise the information is...

I'm interested in particular in "It doesn't matter".

Comment: http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/it%20doesn't%20matter

Comment: I recommend you [edit] your question with your own research results as people tend to close vote it otherwise.

Comment: Another recommendation is to add information about the context where you would like to use this. In oral or in written communication? In a letter to your friend or familiy, in a scientific journal or in a newspaper? There are many ways to express this, and it depends fully on the context which of them is appropriate.

Answer (score 17):

- Es spielt keine Rolle, wie ..
- Es ist egal, wie ..
- Es ist bedeutungslos, wie ..
- Es ist nicht von Belang, wie ..

And more variations of these.

Comment: I’d claim that both in spoken and written German it’s more idiomatic to omit “es ist” before “egal”.

Comment: This answer could be potentially more useful if it went into the exact circumstances in which one phrasing might be preferred over another.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the context the following phrase may fit:

> Ungeachtet der Genauigkeit dieser Angabe/Information ....

(corresponding to *Notwithstanding the precision of this information...*)
which avoids the subordinate clause at the expense of being more formal.

Comment: This is a highly creative answer and the only one that doesn't duplicate a dictionaries' work. +1

Answer (score 7):

One of the most impartial *(wertfrei)* possibilities:

> Unabhängig davon, wie genau die Information ist ...

Answer (score 5):

As was stated in a comment some expressions do have an entry in common dictionaries. Leo e.g. translates it as follows:

> **it doesn't matter** - Es ist ohne Bedeutung

This obviously is one possible translation but it is only half the story and may be a bit clumsy in the given context. There are many other possibilities amongs which I feel the following would suit a professional context:

> **Es ist unerheblich**, wie genau die Information ist...

Answer (score 3):

While most people gave good literal translations that are valid, there is (at least in Austria) one colloquial word for this:

> **Wurscht**

I prefer it above the other options, since it is more natural, and captures the meaning perfectly in one word. You could use it like:

> Wurscht wie genau die Information ist [...]
>
> Die Genauigkeit der Information ist wurscht.

It is also valid if your answer would be "It does not matter.", as in

> Person1: "Ich komme heute später."
>   Person2: "Wurscht."

Comment: It certainly feels more natural to an Austrian speaker, but it should be mentioned that it (I think?) is totally equivalent to "egal" in its function, which sounds less informal.

Comment: So if someone asks how important an internal organ is, ...' liverWurscht' ?

Comment: May I contribute that *wurscht* is not at all restricted to Austria. It is in very common use in larger parts of its northern neighbour (Germany), with the same spelling. Of course it is so informal that you practically never write it.

Comment: @phg: You are correct, and I am surprised "egal" did not come to my mind, as it is more common. For all purposes, it seems to be the better choice (And can indeed be used interchangeably).

Comment: This is strictly informal language. Also: The regular spelling is 'wurst', pronounciation of 'st' varying as usual.

Answer (score 1):

We have always used "Macht nichts"

Comment: That's what my family, of German ancestry, used, but I'm not sure it works as the start of the sentence the OP posed.

Comment: I think you're correct, my German is rusty but how about "Wie genau macht nichts"?

Comment: "Macht nichts" can be translated as "It doesn't matter" but "Macht nichts wie genau die Information ist" does not work. What you can say is "Es macht nichts, wenn die Information ungenau ist". You can say "Macht nichts" when you mean "It doesn't hurt" or "It is not a problem".

Answer (score 1):

This may be more Schweitzerdeutsch, but I learned "Es kommt nicht darauf an" or "Mir ist es gleich".

Comment: Nein, ganz normales Deutsch, das erste neutral, das zweite eben subjektiv.

Answer (score 1):

A formal but common translation would be:

> Es macht keinen Unterschied.. wie genau/präzise die Information ist

Also common:

> Es spielt keine Rolle.. wie genau/präzise die Information ist

Answer (score 0):

I would have used `gegenstandslos` in the sense of the accuracy/truth being `irrelevant`.